# Cannot able to call the contract inside the truffle console

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I am new to the `truffle` framework. I have initialised my contract  `Dapp` with the constructor function as given below

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Dapp {
    uint public totalSupply;

    constructor() public {
        totalSupply = 1000000;
    }
}
```

and my migrations file in regards with the contract is

```
const Dapp = artifacts.require("Dapp");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Dapp);
};
```

I have compiled and migrated using the command `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate`, which results in successful compilation.

But when accessing the contract in `truffle console` like

`let instance = await Dapp.deployed()`

It results in `ReferenceError: Dapp is not defined`, I cannot able to figure out what went wrong. Is there any possible solution to this. And yeah I have followed the latest `Truffle documentaion`.

Documentation link for [migration](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations) and [interacting with truffle console](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts).

My Network is in development mode which is given below

```
networks: {
    development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
}
```

Comment: did you set the location to your private network right? you should check at here: https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration

Comment: Yea I have added @haxerl

Comment: can you provide what private network did you use? and the command to create that network

Comment: Yea, I have added it @haxerl

Answer (score 1):

Okay change your port at truffle-config.js in the network section to 9545 for truffle develop environment. The reason why you can read at here: https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-truffle-develop-and-the-console in the truffle develop section

> This will spawn a development blockchain locally on port 9545, regardless of what your truffle-config.js configuration file calls for

Comment: I have tried that too, its not working

Comment: I think you should post this question on truffle github as an issue maybe they will help you better

Comment: yea I will post this as an issue in truffle GitHub profile. Thanks for the response

Comment: sorry we cant do much

Comment: It's okay, sir. I will try in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not being able to comment instead of adding a new answer.
I wonder if you somehow migrated contracts to Ganache (or a testnet), then tried to access it in `Truffle Develop` blockchain.

Could you upload a minimal repo to Github so that we reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sure and thanks for the response @rgeorgy. GitHub repository link for this project is https://github.com/Thananjaya/EToken